# Where are the best places to Level up Forms?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

I'm trying to learn as many abilities as i can, this includes ones i gain from Level up forms.

Valor Form is easy enough to do since EXP i gained from connecting attacks.

Wisdom Form on the other hand is becoming a pain as it's EXP is gained from killing enemies and i always have 1 party member who keeps taking my kills and i'm finding it hard to find places which have a lot of weak enemies i can kill very quickly.

Master Form (from what i remembered on the PS2) it's EXP is gained from Drive Orbs and i only know that in Agrabah enemies normally drop these.

I'm looking for the best places to Level Up my forms so i can obtain the abilities they give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some general tips for leveling up forms. Use oathkeeper as the Form Boost allows you to stay in forms for longer. If you enter a "room" where your characters are walking around and you can talk to them or go to the gummy ship while in a form it will reset you to basic Sora AND completely refills your drive gauge. Abuse these to always have full drive.

**Valor Form:** Valor is the easiest to level up, all you have to do is hit things. I usually max this out just by virtue of using it on bosses. If you need to grind some levels find some big enemies (such as those in beasts castle or radiant garden). Equip low strength keyblades so you can hit more often before killing and go to town.

**Wisdom Form:** Wisdom needs to level by killing heartless. To this end you should try to find large amounts of weak heartless you can kill quickly with one or two spells. The best place is the "city" part of The World That Never Was. Down in the street shadows spawn seemingly without end, this allows you to level up very quickly. The four curtains in Timeless River also have weak heartless all game if you dont like or dont want to wait for the world that never was.

**Master Form:** Master form levels off drive orbs. Similar to Valor you are going to want to seek out big enemies as they usually drop the most orbs. Additionally I like equipping sweet memories as it converts munny drops to drive orbs. The best places to level are Beasts Castle or The Land of Dragons. In beasts castle just kill the large enemies in your favorite spot (I usually do the courtyard). In the land of dragons go to the village and fight the large enemies on the mountains and in the cave. If you blow up the firework stands they will also drop quite a bit of drive orbs.

**Final Form:** You can get Final Form after the fight with Roxas in the world that never was. After this fight any time you enter a form you have a random chance of entering final form instead. Once you have entered it the first time you are then able to enter it via the drive menu. Final Form levels up by killing nobodies. The best places for this are the world that never was and Yen Sid's tower in twilight town.

**Limit Form:** Limit form is new to final mix. You get it as part of the story when you revisit twilight town. Limit Form levels up by using the ending part of a limit combo. Limit form usually has enough mana to use two limits before running out. At higher levels (or with ethers) you can refill you mana and use more limits. The important part is that you actually finish the limit. Getting hit or running out of enemies will end the limit prematurely. This can be leveled anywhere that has enemies you can use limits on.

**Anti Form:** Anti Form cannot be leveled up.

Comment: For Final Form. The Save Point in the room with the Org XIII guys "Gravestones". After beating both of them and after you talk to Ansem you can go into each of the four adjacent areas (the two boss rooms and the two adjacent hallways) and fight about 6-8 Nobodies a piece. If you go in order the rooms will always have enemies and you will always have full drive form since you will only ever be one room from the save point.

Comment: For Master Form, the Cavern of Remembrance is a good place to level. There are little balloons which drop drive balls. If you go to the second set of two, activate Master, and then run back through to the beginning, you can hop back out to the world map and repeat to level it pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For Limit Form, the 1000 heartless is an amazing way to max out limits. It cuts out the time it takes for you to refill your MP at a save point/leaving the world to refill your drive. All you need is Vicinity Break and as many MP Rages as possible (I think I had 2... One from the keyblade and one ability). Use Sonic Rave once, refill a bit with MP Rage (so you don't go into MP Charge), and just keep repeating that until you're about to run out of your form gauge (one cast of Sonic Rave used, on average, a gauge and a half. If you hit more enemies, it'll use more). Then just go into MP Charge by using Sonic Rave one last time and revert if you haven't yet run out of your form gauge. Since you're already in MP Charge, you can easily fill up your drive gauge to 4 by running into a group of heartless and using Vicinity Break. One Vicinity Break can fill almost an entire drive bar. Rinse and repeat. I got from level 1 to level 6 (can't get Final Form until after) and still had around 300 heartless left. Not sure if the OP still needs this, but hopefully, this helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

The organization heartless in the cave of wonders is a good way to level up limit form and valor form. Use low key blades so he doesn't die fast. Wisdom form I used Hercules world a lot and Halloween town!

Answer (score -2):

Go to Agrabah to the Cave of Wonders and hit the Organization XIII Mushroom in treasure room to level up the Valor form.